# BLE Beacon Scanning with Luch

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, listener, beacon

I am playing around with the BLE beacon scanner library [Luch](https://github.com/agap/luch) in Kotlin.
To scan for beacons I did the following (which is working):

```
   val beaconScanner = BeaconScanner.Builder(context)
        .setBeaconParser(beaconParser)
        .setBeaconBatchListener { beacons ->
            for (beacon in beacons) {
                val beaconPower = beacon.txPower
            }
        }
        .setRangingEnabled()
        .build()

    beaconScanner.start()
```

However, to calculate the distance for one beacon, one has to use the `Ranger` class. The code example is:

```
val ranger = beaconScanner.getRanger()
val distance = ranger.calculateDistance(beacon)
```

Since the `beaconScanner` object is a listener, I don't know how to reference the beacon list outside. I tried to save the returned `beacons`-list and to access it after starting the scanning but this does not seem to work. Inside the `setBeaconBatchListener` I cannot call the `calculateDistance` function because it is part of the `Ranger` class which I don't have access to inside the listener.

Can someone please help me and tell me how this works with listeners?